# Ambiguating new declaration of 'void scan_fraction(int*, int*)'

Tags: c

I am trying to compile my code and this error is popping up:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//Prototype
int scan_fraction(int *nump, int *denomp);
//Execution
int main ()
{
    int nump, denomp;
    scan_fraction(&nump, &denomp); 
}
//Definition
void  scan_fraction(int *nump, int *denomp)
        {
        char slash; /* character between numerator and denominator */
        int status; /* status code returned by scanf indicating
        number of valid values obtained */
        int error; /* flag indicating presence of an error */
        char discard; /* unprocessed character from input line */


    do {
        /* No errors detected yet */
        error = 0;
        /* Get a fraction from the user */
        printf("Enter a common fraction as two integers separated ");
        printf("by a slash> ");
        status = scanf("%d %c%d",&nump, &slash, denomp);
        /* Validate the fraction */
        if (status < 3) {
        error = 1;
        printf("Invalid-please read directions carefully\n");
        } else if (slash != '/') {
        error = 1;
        printf("Invalid-separate numerator and denominator");
        printf(" by a slash (/)\n");
        } else if (denomp <= 0) {
        error = 1;
        printf("Invalid—denominator must be positive\n");
    }
    /* Discard extra input characters */
    do {
    scanf("%c", &discard);
    } while (discard != '\n');
    } while (error);
}
```

What could be the error? Can somebody explain to me why it is the error. I'm still learning at C.

Comment: On which line the error is popping up? Please [edit] your question and make that clear _there_

Comment: Forward declaration has `int` return whilst definition has `void`.

Comment: BTW: unrelated to your question: `status = scanf("%d %c%d", &nump, &slash, denomp);` the scanf format string is wrong. Compile with all warnings enabled and consider warnings as errors.

Comment: thanks Jabberwocky and kaylum. got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declare this:

```
int scan_fraction(int* nump, int* denomp);
```

And your implementation is this:

```
void scan_fraction(int* nump, int* denomp)
```

Declaration and implementation don't match.

---

Also, you have:

```
status = scanf("%d %c%d", &nump, &slash, denomp);
```

You should use this, because `nump` is already a pointer to `int`:

```
status = scanf("%d %c%d", nump, &slash, denomp);
```

Your compiler should be telling you about this, too.